# The best way of eliminating semi-duplicate! records in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some records like

```
a,b
b,a
a,c
c,a
b,d
d,b
b,f
f,b
...
```

in my query result. (They are emails) 
What is the best way to have:

```
a,b
a,c 
b,d
b,f
```

and eliminate b,a and c,a, d,b, f,b?

I tried

```
SELECT *
FROM ...
WHERE MOD(ROWNUM/2)=0
```

But it just returns the first row

Answer (score 7):

How about ...

```
select distinct
  least(col1,col2) col1,
  greatest(col1, col2) col2
from
  my_table
```

Comment: or `distinct least(col, regexp_replace(col, '^(.*),(.*)$', '\2,\1'))` in case of comma separated list of emails

Answer (score 1):

Good answer from David,

An answer with standard SQL:

```
select a,b from (
  select 
    (case when col1 < col2  
          then col1
          else col2
      end) as a,
    (case when col1 > col2  
          then col1
          else col2
      end) as b
from t )
group by a,b
order by a,b;
```

Sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c63b7/1

Comment: Both statements give wrong [results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/134f3/1) with nulls.

Comment: just add `is null` check in case clause.